# How can I change the terminal title to current running program name?

Tags: xfce, xfce4-terminal

In Konsole we can use `%d: %n` to set the tab title as "current dir: running program". Is there anyway to do this  in xfce4-terminal?

If not, at least I want to put current dir infront of the user@hostname. The user@hostname are too long to make reasonable notification about current dir  when I do `alt-tab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%w` is the key. So basically we canuse PS1 to set the window title. In PS1 we can use [ANSI control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences) `ESC ]0;` to set the window title. Then in terminal emulator we use `%w` to display that value. In .bashrc we can do:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${last_cmd}\]$PS1"
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71467884/1492613) describes how to get the last_cmd in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

The %n switch does not work with xfce4-terminal, but the %d one does. From the XFCE4 docs, the terminal supports these substitutions:

- %d : name of the current directory (short).
- %D : current directory (long).
- %w : window title set by shell.
- %# : the session id.